# How to structure my query in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, date, time

I would like to retrieve today's data. At the moment I have something like `SELECT * FROM  myTable  WHERE timeStamp>DATETIME('NOW','-1 DAY')` but this gives me results from now to 24hrs back, not just today (i.e. no matter how many hours have passed since 00:00). Using the same logic I want to retrieve data for just yesterday, and for the this week.

**[EDIT]**
By the term this week i mean.. if today is Thursday, i want to show results from monday or Sunday (it doesnt matter) upto now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `timeStamp > DATETIME('now')` use `timeStamp >= DATE('now')`.

For since yesterday you can use `DATE('now', '-1 day')`.

As for this week - it depends if you mean 7 days ago:

```
DATE('now', '-7 days')
```

Or if you mean since the beginning of the first day of this week:

```
DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days')
```

Comment: what does the greater than catch in this `timeStamp >= DATE('now')`. I mean what is the difference with this  `timeStamp == DATE('now')`?

Comment: if your timeStamp includes times as well as dates, then '==' won't match unless the timeStamp occurred exactly at midnight.  If you aren't storing times at all (just dates) then the only difference would be if you wanted to include dates later than today.  If you don't have those either, then it won't matter

Comment: timestamp is in this form `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: as for yesterday shall i use `timeStamp == DATE('now','-1 day')` ?

Comment: i guess it should have the same problem as you mention above so something like `timeStamp <= DATE('now','-1 day') AND timeStamp >= DATE('now','-2 day')` ?

Comment: That would retrieve the date for two days ago.  If you wanted just yesterday you can do this: `DATE(timeStamp) == DATE('now', '-1 day')` because putting the timeStamp inside the `DATE()` function will remove the time for you

Comment: cool. thanks! I have updated my question to specify what i mean by week, so i guess it's the correct would be the second one

Comment: DATE('now', 'weekday 0', '-7 days') seems not to work properly as i get zero results for this week...while total is 4 and all the 4 of them happened this week

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8318/discussion-between-pinnym-and-justcurious)