# how to delete last 2 days entry form a table in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

i m trying like this:

```
char *Query =  "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE starttime < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";
```

Comment: I just formatted your code and then your reverted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,to delete last 2 days,you need to check data greater than the specified date,then you need to use `DATE('now', '-1 days')` to get the date,more details can be found at [How to structure my query in sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470990/how-to-structure-my-query-in-sqlite)

```
DELETE FROM bandwidthmaster WHERE starttime > DATE('now', '-1 days');
```

Comment: it is deleting whole data  ,not only last 2 days.

Comment: @ShivamSharma Have you tested it? My answer will not delete whole data to only last 2 days.

Comment: Yeah i just tested it and it is working fine thanks.

Comment: I have another question , i have row id and i want to delete whole data till this row id number how can i delete .

Comment: @ShivamSharma `DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE id=?` will this simple SQL meet your demand?

Comment: yeah its working fine, i have done this using this command i just want to confirm.ThankYou

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to open password protected db in sqlite3 using c++.(i mean programmatically)

Comment: @ShivamSharma Sorry,I am not familar with it,I think you can ask a new question for it